# Use mechanize and beautiful soup on a webpage that did not enable javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a webpage but it requires me to log in first. I am new to web scraping so please bear with my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.open('https://mywebsite.com')
# browser.select_form(name = 'form2')
# browser.form['Account Name'] = 'username'
# browser.form['Password'] = 'mypassword'
# browser.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.response().read())
print soup
```

However i am getting this error:

```
<html><head><script language="javascript">
<!--.
    .
    .
</script>
<noscript>
<title>No JavaScript Error</title>
<body>
<h3 align="center">Your Browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled.<br/>To run this application, you must enable JavaScript!!</h3>
</body></noscript></head></html>
```

Comment: I don't think that's an error: plenty of pages include a no-script version of their markup. It's probably replaced by the script if it runs.

Comment: what can i do to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following header instead, server may not recognise your header and therefore it may cause it to think that you don't have javascript enabled:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
```

Note: some websites have anti-scraping protection and you will have to solve javascript puzzles to get actual content. You can use [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) for that or any other javascript runtime. Scraping this kind of websites is much harder but fortunately few websites use this system.